# Ubuntu 12.04/13.10 - system running in low graphics mode error on Asus VIA A8V-MX

Tags: 12.04, 13.10, livedvd

I am getting this error when booting a Live-DVD image also. After installation my system hangs when I click the "restart now" button. After a hard shutdown it says

> The system is running in low graphics mode

I am not having any trouble with the first version of Ubuntu 12.04, it runs fine even after upgrading, so some modification made between the initial release of 12.04 and now has resulted in this incompatibility.

I am getting the same error while installing Lubuntu 12.04.

My motherboard is Asus VIA A8V-MX with integrated graphics card.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up your [motherboard on newegg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131558) and see that you have a S3 Graphics UniChrome Pro IGP video adaptor.

When I searched for your video card and Ubuntu your error immediately popped up on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-openchrome/+bug/1205643

According to launchpad, this bug has been resolved in the new Ubuntu LTS (14.04).  You can either use the earlier install from 12.04 and don't upgrade xserver-xorg-video-openchrome or you can try installing the new 14.04 beta (due to be officially released very soon).

Comment: Thanks for replying. Ubuntu 14.04 bootup and runs. But it was very laggy. when i looked up it shows that CPU is 100% and i think compiz is taking all of it. Thus it has become almost impossible to use. How to solve this problem or where to report it?

Comment: My guess is that there is no or minimal hardware accelerated graphics and since Ubuntu uses 3D for Unity it is thrashing your CPU.  I'm not sure if Ubuntu lets you disable compiz any more.  Maybe try Xubuntu instead to get a fast UI?

Comment: right now i am using bodhi linux. but i will check with lubuntu or xubuntu